# Does the "luk" space suit in Seveneves make sense?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, space-mission

Tiny spoiler of the book [Seveneves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves) ahead.

Early in the book, the Russian space agency develops an onion-like space suit called the "luk" (the Russian word for [onion](http://translate.google.com/#en/ru/onion)). It works like this:

- A cosmononaut is encased in a plastic bag pressured at 1 ATM.
- Since such a bag might burst due to the extreme pressure differential in space, this bag is itself placed in another bag pressured at 0.9 ATM.
- In turn, this second bag is placed in a third bag pressured at 0.8 ATM, etc all the way to a last envelop which must only contain 0.1 ATM.

The idea is that each bag only has to resist 0.1 ATM of net pressure.

Question: wouldn't a bag 10 times as thick as each of the individual bag be able to hold 1 ATM? Am I missing something?

Comment: Define "better." Also, might [space.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: POssible analogy:  consider a linear series of weak springs and the net force they can withstand.